# Populating lists with the workflow in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, workflow, sharepoint-designer

Hey all, I am currently building a workflow, i created a list (let say list A), when the user fills out the list (form) and clicks OK button the workflow kick starts. the first action of workflow should be populating all the fields(whatever filled by user) in the List A to List B (here list B has same columns as list A but some additional columns). How to built this action in workflow. Any thoughts are highly appreciated. Quite a newbie to Sharepoint, eager to learn more about it.

Suppose List A has name field, its being filled as XYZ, then workflow should be able to populate XYZ in same corresponding name field in List B. I hope I made it clear

Trying to build workflow in sharepoint designer 2007 (Article would be great Help)

I think I would need to map them individually with the workflow properties. How Could I map them individually with workflow properties, Could some one explain in detail

Answer (score 0):

You might find this useful:
http://www.fivenumber.com/copy-item-from-one-list-to-another-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow/